# Can unicode chars in sql queries cause slow db performance?

Tags: sql, database, performance, hibernate

Can use of unicode chars in queries cause database to slow down?

I am using a query like

```
Select * from table where name='xyz¿½'
```

After this query my application slows down permanently until I restart it.

I am using c3p0 hibernate's connection pool

Comment: Is the `name` column indexed? What type is it? What database are you using?

Comment: What is slowing down - your application on the client or queries to the server - as with all performance questions measure which bit is slow.

Comment: What database server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that sybase does not use an index when query contains unicode characters. It may be due to some charset settings in my version.

Answer (score 0):

A modern database should support Unicode, but that may be restricted to certain data types.

For example SQL Server only supports Unicode for the following data types:

```
nchar
nvarchar
nvarchar(max) – new in SQL Server 2005
ntext
```

Unicode string constants (say within stored procedures/functions) should be preceded with the letter N e.g. `N'abcd'`